# C++ Class instantiation problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have included the proper

> Header Files  , 
>   Header Gard

but i cannot instantiate a specific class

Getting Error

```
error C2065: 'ClassName' : undeclared identifier



Sample Code

Class A{

 //instantiate class B

}


Class B {


 //need to instantiate Class A

}
```

Comment: I can instantiate  other classes

Comment: Would you paste any code? A minimal complete example that fails to work

Comment: You might want to add some more informations to your question, e.g. the actual code where you get the error. Going from what you've written possible answers are a) you didn't actually include the header or b) your instatiation is wrong, but that would not be very helpful I'd guess

Comment: i cant instantiate that class in any of other classes

Comment: may be circular dependency..unless you post some code we will never know.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewcf0002(v=VS.90).aspx First point of checking errors.

Comment: I have described the scenario :)

Comment: NO. you have described NOTHING.

Comment: Post some *real* code which shows the problem.

Comment: If you have actually included the `.h` files properly, and those files include the class declaration (but not definition), then this will absolutely work correctly. The fact that you are getting an error proves something is not done right, but without seeing your actual code nobody here can possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any real code for us to actually make use of, I'll take a guess as to what your code actually looks like:

A.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_A
#define HEADER_A

#include "B.h"
class A {
private:
  B someMember;
};
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_B
#define HEADER_B
#include "A.h"

class B {
public:
  doSomething(A param);
};
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void B::doSomething(A param) { }
```

As Flinsch said, you need to have forward declarations to avoid problems with include ordering. The simplest way is to get rid of the circular includes in the .h files and just include the forward declarations (`class B;` and `class A;` into A.h and B.h) instead.

Answer (score 1):

btw. you don't have `;` at the end of class definition.

Comment: NO you describe NO scenario, because there is NO real code, and NO instanciation written. Your question just a fuzzy joke for us for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Under my understanding there is a circular dependency between classes A and B. So you need to use forward declaration for at least one of those two classes (or even both).

Comment: My Classes are in separate .cpp files any idea ?

Comment: Yes, that's the standard procedure to have a separate .cpp file for each class. And *what* "all of them" have you done? You don't really want to get help, do you?